# Shell Scripting editor in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: scripts

I want to do some Shell Scripting on my Ubuntu 13.10 (32-bit) desktop. How can I create Shell Scripts using the editor. Since I am not familiar with the Ubuntu editor Gedit. Is it possible to do it with Vim. If yes, then which package would be suitable for me.

Comment: This question shows a basic misunderstanding of what a shell script is. You can use whichever editor to write a shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install vim, do `sudo apt-get install vim`.

You don't need any other package if you want to write shell scripts. You can use `vi <filename>` to write the scripts and `bash <filename>` to execute the scripts using bash shell, `sh <filename>` to execute using `sh` shell, `dash <filename>` using dash.

If you need other shells like `zsh`, `fish`, etc., you'll need to install them using `sudo apt-get install zsh` or whatever package-name.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Actually I am new to Linux systems. Thanks again.